# jQuery .nothas?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to do the equivalent of a `.nothas()` selector in jQuery?  For example, if I wanted to add a `TBODY` to all `TABLE` elements that didn't already have one, it would be nice to do something like this:

```
$("TABLE").nothas("TBODY").append("<TBODY />");
```

It would be even better if this could be limited to direct descendents, so that (in this case) `TABLE` elements embedded in `THEAD` cells wouldn't be considered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery has [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selectors:

```
$("table:not(:has(tbody))").append("<tbody />");
```