# Css3 under class

Tags: html, css, class

How use css3 selector to under class ?

```
<div>
     <span>Example Text</span>
</div>
```

i used `div:not(span)` but doesn't work.(I think that Not support only div class) Anyone have idea ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I understand that you may not be a native English speaker but the question is very unclear. `div:not(span)` will not work because... well, a `div` is not a `span`.

Comment: Sorry that isn't explained well, im trying to use div class when "div" doesn't have anything

<div> </div>

Not <div><span></span</div>

Comment: You mean the select the `div` when it is totally empty or only when it doesn't have a `span` inside? Former is possible using CSS but the latter is not.

Comment: so how ? - I am ready for any possibility

Answer (score 0):

Use `div > span { ... }` to address direct child elements (without another layer in between), `div span { ... }` for *all* `<span>` elements inside a `<div>`

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is after. He seems to be trying to select the parent (depending on if it has a span child) and not the child.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```css
.test {
  background: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.test:empty {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"><!-- I will be lime --></div>
<div class="test">I will be red</div>
<div class="test">
    <!-- SHould be black around here -->
</div>
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aempty

very good library of resource: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Comment: div > span = div span ?

I want to exclude span.

When DIV doesnt have under class span

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Your question was unclear... Can you give me a scenario?

Comment: Sorry but I can't edit.

 im trying to use div class when "div" doesn't have anything <div> </div> Not <div><span></span</div>

Comment: So i must use selector when div doesn't have podclass "span"

Comment: So you want to check if the <div> tag has any other elements such as a <span> or a <p> tags and if it doesn't you want to apply some style

Comment: @PatrykGtfo Check my answer updated and you should be able to apply what i've done to your project

Comment: thats because theres no whitespace around it, you should't have text in a <div> anyway

Comment: but i must have text :D

its for button

Comment: Use a <a> tag for a btn, or give the div a class of btn and apply styles to the class

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may use the `:empty` psudo class ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aempty)) to select a div which does not contain other elements. In your case, `div:empty` would select a div element which does not contain a span element (or any other elements, or text, **or whitespace**). It may not be exactly what you need, but it's all I know of.

Comment: Its correct, but i must have text <div> TEXT </div> So its not working

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery or any JavaScript in this solution?

Comment: yea, but i want use only css. If isn't possible i resigns

Comment: Well, if nothing else comes up, I'll point you in the direction of `$("div:not(:has(span))")` to select the div elements that do not contain span elements. From there you can perform any jQuery operation on the collection of returned elements, like adding a custom class or style. This solution is based on the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979461/jquery-nothas